# Bootstrap 4 Navbar column size is not 100%

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a BS 4 Navbar and it looks fine on Desktop but when I toggle to mobile, the column inside the navbar is not filling the whole space, hence the width is not 100%.  The purple area in the screenshot below:

[image]

When I inspect the code, looks like there is this `flex-wrap: wrap;` that is preventing the column width to go 100% on mobile. If I uncheck and disable `flex-wrap: wrap;` then the items in the nav and the Join/Apply links look jumbled up.

What's causing this and how to fix it? All I want is for my Join/Apply buttons to be 100% of the mobile device size.

This is my HTML and I don't use a custom css code to change the default sizing of the columns or rows.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse nav-fill w-100 collapse show" id="collapsing_navbar" style="">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-nav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#explore">Academics</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#rankings">Rankings</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#surrounds">Surrounds</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-nav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#advantage">Work</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#living-sustainably">Living Sustainably</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#how-we-serve">How We Serve</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row d-sm-none mobile-nav-show">
        <div class="col">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link visit text-white">Visit</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav-link apply text-white">Apply</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is one of the bootstrap classes has `flex-wrap: wrap` and you would have to that specific style.

You could add a media query such that the `flex-wrap` will only apply to desktop screen sizes. One such way to do it would be to use a media query:

You could have it such as

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .class-that-has-flex-wrap {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
}
```

This sets the `flex-wrap` to `nowrap` which is basically the opposite of `flex-wrap: wrap`. This only affects screen sizes less than or equal to 480px. This breakpoint may be different for you.

Comment: I tried that. It's the .navbar > .container and setting it to nowrap jumbles up the nav items and the Visit/Apply buttons at the bottom.

Comment: do you have any additional css? I tried running the HTML with the bootstrap CDN and I'm unable to replicate it here https://jsbin.com/gutigisico/2/edit?html,output 
Can you share a fiddle?